# I cannot able to pass data with using protocol in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, protocols

I have a xibs, in my homeVC, I m passing a viewModel in didselectItem in collectionView's method. After that, I m navigating detailVC and I assign my delegate to self there but I could not my print data

**HomeVC**

```
protocol HomeViewControllerDelegate {
func didTappedIndex(viewModel: HomeCollectionViewCellViewModel)}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let game = games[indexPath.row]

    self.delegate?.didTappedIndex(viewModel: HomeCollectionViewCellViewModel(with: game))
    
    self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(nibName: "DetailViewController", bundle: nil), animated: true)
    
}
```

**DetailVC**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    HomeViewController().delegate = self
}
```

}

extension DetailViewController: HomeViewControllerDelegate {

```
func didTappedIndex(viewModel: HomeCollectionViewCellViewModel) {
    print(viewModel.title)
}
```

}

Comment: `HomeViewController().delegate = self` `HomeViewController()` is short syntax for `HomeViewController-.inti()`. So you are creating a NEW instance of `HomeViewController`, you're not settings the delegate to the one you seen on screen, but on another one (which isn't used afterwards).

Comment: @Larme sorry I could not understand you, so what should I do in this situation

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: @matt it summarizes exactly my situation  thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call

```
HomeViewController().delegate = self
```

you are creating a new instance of HomeViewController().  You are probably confusing this instance with one you've created somewhere else.  You want to assign the delegate of the correct HomeViewController.

one option would be to add an instance variable and shared function to the HomeViewController that allows it to keep track of its instance:

```
private static var instance: HomeViewController?

internal class func shared() -> HomeViewController {
    guard let currentInstance = instance else {
        instance = HomeViewController()
        return instance!
    }
    return currentInstance
}
```

then you can set the delegate in DetailViewController like this:

```
HomeViewController.shared().delegate = self
```

Another option would be to have a Coordinator where you keep track of all view controllers. Then you could pass the DetailViewController the HomeViewController instance.